# How to fill select-options with js?

Tags: javascript

I have an ajax request. I can't fill options of select tag. I've a lot of blocks where select tag has the same point - select a type of product.

My select tag:

```
<select class="form-control" name="type" id="select-types">
</select>
```

My ajax request:

```
function getTypes() {
 $.ajax({
      url: `/types/json`
  }).done(function(res){
    console.log(res)
    })}
```

"res" is a type of this : `{types: [{"id":1,"name": Name}, ...]}`

For example I have 5 blocks with the same select.

1.How to fill only last of them ?

2.How to fill it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to grab the last element would be to use the `getElementsByTagName`, then, to include each option in the `select` you want, You can traverse the list of types and create an `option` for each type and finally append it on the `select`.

```js
const types = [{"id":1,"name": "Something"}, {"id":2,"name": "New Text"}];
const allSelects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
const lastSelect = allSelects[allSelects.length - 1];

types.forEach((type) => {
  const option = document.createElement("option");

  option.value = type.id;
  option.text = type.name;
  
  lastSelect.appendChild(option)
})
```

Comment: Thank's everyone. I prefer this answer

Answer (score 1):

1. you can use `.slice(0, 5)` to limit options up to 5 items
2. you can change `innerHTML` of your select to generate options

```js
const fakeRequest = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve([
      'opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3', 'opt4', 'opt5', 'opt6', 'opt7'
    ])
  }, 1000)
})

const select = document.getElementById('select-types')

fakeRequest().then(options => {
  const showingOptions = options.slice(0, 5)
  select.innerHTML = showingOptions.map(value => `<option value='${value}'>${value}</option>`)
})
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="type" id="select-types">
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Map the type list to option html syntax, and join to one string.  Then set as the select's innerHTML.

```
function getTypes() {
 $.ajax({
      url: `/types/json`
  }).done(function(res) {
       let select = document.getElementById('select-types');    
       let options = 
          res.types.map(type => `<option value=${type.id}>${type.name}</option>`)
                   .join('\n');
       select.innerHTML = options;
  });
}
```